# How to get latest result set based on the timestamp in amazon qldb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb

I have many an IonStruct as follows.

```
{
  revenueId: "0dcb7eb6-8cec-4af1-babe-7292618b9c69",
  ownerId: "u102john2021",
  revenueAddedTime: 2020-06-20T19:31:31.000Z,

}
```

I want to write a query to select the latest records set within a given year.

for example, suppose I have a set of timestamps like this -
A - 2019-06-20T19:31:31.000Z
B - 2020-06-20T19:31:31.000Z
C - 2020-06-20T19:31:31.000Z
D - 2021-07-20T19:31:31.000Z
E - 2020-09-20T19:31:31.000Z
F - 2020-09-20T19:31:31.000Z

If the selected year is between 2020 and 2021, I want to return records which having the latest timestamp.
in this case. E and F,

I tried many ways like

```
"SELECT * FROM REVENUES AS r WHERE r.ownerId = ? AND r.revenueAddedTime >= ? AND r.revenueAddedTime < ?"
```

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have no experience in qldb syntax, it seems to have similar properties to other db syntax in the sense that you can format your timestamps using these doc:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-functions.timestamp-format.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-functions.to_timestamp.html

Once you format the timestamp, you may be able to do the `>` and `<` query syntax.

Comment: Actually, why should I format the time stamp? My problem is to get the latest record set for the given year. with > < how can i do that?